# Pasting into VScode terminal adds "~" character at the end

Tags: visual-studio-code

When pasting something like "id=j5ee8cea-a22d-8ac3-a22k-bc740dxbe4e0" in the VS code terminal it adds the "~" character at the end. Example: "id=j5ee8cea-a22d-8ac3-a22k-bc740dxbe4e0~" . This only happens for this type of text. Other strings paste normally. Is there a possibility to remove this?

Already uncheck the option "File -> preferences -> Settings -> Editor: Format On Paste", but it keeps putting the sign "~" at the end.

Comment: Be careful, I think for me it added `0~`, not just `~`, which caused some confusion. Is this Bash?

Comment: cannot reproduce. add version numbers for all your things: OS, VS Code, shell, etc.

Comment: Hello, the "0" is part of the string. it only added the same "~", in the terminal, when I pasted it.
My OS version = Windows 10.
The version of VSCODE = 1.81.1

Comment: Are you sure it's this particular "type of text"? Is that the complete string you are pasting, or is the actual string longer? I'm finding the same thing happening, but only when the string being pasted is 90 characters or longer in length. See [VS Code Issue #193125](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/193125) which I just filed. If the input is 91 characters it adds a `~` as you mentioned. If the input is 91 characters it adds a `0~` as @HolyBlackCat mentioned.